# How to get the base address of a process in C++ Internally?

Tags: memory-address

I know a function that I want to hook is at "ac_client.exe" + 63fe. How to find out what is the base address of the running executable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [GetModuleHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199(VS.85).aspx). Pass in `NULL`, like this:

```
GetModuleHandler(NULL);
```

It will return the handle for the current running module (the `.exe`), which is actually its base address.

In case you want to know the base address of a different (loaded) module, like a `DLL`, then just pass its name.

Comment: I wanted to thank you but it warn me that i should not do that.

Comment: I cannot my score is too low this is my first question

Answer (score 4):

The speediest solution especially for game hacking where GetModuleHandle may be hooked.

```
const auto peb = reinterpret_cast<PPEB>(__readfsdword(0x30));
const auto base = peb->Reserved3[1];
```